# multiparts email in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, html-email

I have a problem with sending emails consisting of text/plain and text/html parts.

```
--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-ID: <email.text/plain>

TEXT email
```

After sending the message only the HTML part is visible.
If I remove the HTML part and leave only the text/plain then the text part is sent correctly.

The attachments are sent correctly.

I would like to be able to send emails consisting of two parts: html and text with attachments.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

```
function createMail
{
local EMAIL
EMAIL=${1}

cat > ${MAIL_FILE} << EOF
From: ${MAIL_FROM}
To: ${EMAIL}
Cc: ${TO_RECIPIENTS_CC}
Bcc: ${TO_RECIPIENTS_BCC}
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?${SUBJECT}?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MixedBoundaryString"

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="RelatedBoundaryString"

--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="AlternativeBoundaryString"

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-ID: <email.text/plain>

**TEXT email**

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/html;
Content-ID: <email.text/html>

<html>
  <head>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
      <p>HTML email</p>
      <p><img border=0 width=1024 height=503 style='width:10.6666in;height:5.2416in' id=id.obrazek1 src="cid:id.obrazek1" alt="Opis: cid:id.obrazek1"></p>
  </body>
</html>

--AlternativeBoundaryString--


--RelatedBoundaryString
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=$(basename 'picture_png.png')
Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode
Content-ID: <id.obrazek1>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="picture_png.png"

$(python -c 'import sys,uu; uu.encode("picture_png.png", sys.stdout)')

--RelatedBoundaryString--


--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain; name=$(basename 'test_log.log')
Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test_log.log"

$(uuencode test_log.log test_log.log )


--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain; name=$(basename 'test_pdf.pdf')
Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test_pdf.pdf"

$(python -c 'import sys,uu; uu.encode("test_pdf.pdf", sys.stdout)')

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name=$(basename 'test_excel.xlsx')
Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test_excel.xlsx"

$(python -c 'import sys,uu; uu.encode("test_excel.xlsx", sys.stdout)')

--MixedBoundaryString--

EOF
}


function sendMail
{

cat ${MAIL_FILE} | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t 

}
```

Comment: UUOC: use `sendMail() { /usr/sbin/sendmail -t < "$MAIL_FILE"; }`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything.